# javascript navigator.onLine checks only system connected with internet device not internet

Tags: javascript, angular

I have used `navigator.onLine` to determine whether my system is connected to the internet or not, but it only evaluates the system is connected with wifi or another device. Suppose the system is connected with wifi, but has no internet. Then it returns `true`.
Any solutions or I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: This is not a JavaScript problem, it is a general networking problem. You will have to try to load a page from the internet to determine whether it is reachable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it works.
The **navigator.online** checks if the device is connected to a network or not.
Let it be a real network LAN or WIFI (with or without internet) or some virtual network when using a live server.

You can try to simulate being offline using the Firefox browser and select work offline and you will see that **navigator.online** returns **false**.